# Redux Toolkit - global reject

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux Toolkit, and I have a bunch of slices.
I have one particular slice called `sessionSlice` , which contains a few `extraReducers`, that import `thunks` from other slices, like the following:

```
    [fetchDashboardUserReq.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      setSessionExpired(state, action);
    },
    [fetchDashboardUsersReq.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      setSessionExpired(state, action);
    },
    [fetchDashboardAchievementsReq.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      setSessionExpired(state, action);
    },
```

The `setSessionExpired` is checking if the error is due to the user having its session expired.
I'm doing this for a bunch of different `createAsyncThunk`s - is there a way to have a "global" `rejected` function, where I could check for this? Instead of having so much duplicated code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do it in the redux middleware, make a custom middleware function, it that function identifies session expired error on any request then dispatch a special action without calling next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use the builder callback notation of `extraReducers' together with a matcher.

[Example from the docs:](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation)

```js
function isRejectedAction(action) {
  return action.type.endsWith('rejected')
}

createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        isRejectedAction,
        (state, action) => {
          // ...
        }
      )
  },
})
```

But keep in mind that reducers must not have side effects, so your `setSessionExpired` method must only modify `state`, nothing external. Otherwise you'd have to use a middleware.